# php strong ban system based on ip address

Tags: php

I have a social networking website I want build a banning system based on ip address. About how we can control a user with dynamic ip address? If I will block user based on account he/she can create new account. What will be best solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can't, and nor should you.

An IP address does not uniquely identify a user.  It could be anywhere from one user to an entire country.  If they have a dynamic IP from their ISP, then their IP will change, and the only thing you could do is block the whole ISP... not a good idea.

Even if you could block by IP, it doesn't matter, as someone could use a proxy.

Ban their account instead.  Link the account to an e-mail address.  Basically, make it more of a hassle to get around being banned instead.  That's the best you can do.

Comment: To add; if not already implemented use a captcha, or alternative bot filter, to prevent malicious users from generating large numbers of accounts that would have to be batch-banned.

Comment: Also, you could ban by IP, and then look into preventing proxy sites from accessing your website, essentially nullifying the use of proxies.

Comment: @Nightfirecat, that only provides a temporary solution though. Often you can get new IPs by resetting your router. I also get a new IP address every time I connect to my mobile network, college network or friend's or family's WiFi.

Comment: @jordanmoore True, but often, blocking somebody once is enough to deter them from trying further. It's even less likely that said blocked person knows how to circumvent it.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I tend to agree with you with that view. Though it is possible said blocked person could accidentally circumvent it when trying to visit another day - but yes - blocking a user like this may be enough for them to take their bothers elsewhere. Only reason I commented was because the OP is after a strong ban system, and I don't believe IP banning can achieve this for him.

Comment: @Brad. You are correct, however, the new EU GDPR in effect since April 2018, DOES consider an IP address to be PII information. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use something like this:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
    localStorage['banned'] = '1';
}
```

Noobs will never know that you're blocking them through HTML 5 Local Storage.

Comment: Most browsers when you do a full "delete history / cookies" include local storage now; too.