# IP Filter with PHP

Tags: php, filter, ip, ip-address

I was looking for a way to create an IP filter, so that I could easily identify customers, but many examples I saw, I could not understand in a way.

Then, I come here with some questions
A customer enters my site, IP x recovered from  `$_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR']`, but I've been reading some things about CRID, which is one way to check if this IP is on the list denied, because obviously 90% of customers accessing the site, when you restart the modem IP is changed, I do not know if I'm talking nonsense, but a good idea to create an IP filter?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. `when you restart the modem IP is changed`

Comment: I don't think PHP is the place to filter IP's..  That should be addressed in the servers firewall configuration.

Comment: No Paul, when Client restart the modem, his IP is changed, if ip is changed, i can't match by equality `OLD IP === NEW IP`, i think have other way

Comment: Just to clarify: What is the reason, that you want to create an ip-filter?

Comment: @AndreyKnupp - That's my point. You can't accurately identify someone by their IP address because of their dynamic nature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php strong ban system based on ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107842/php-strong-ban-system-based-on-ip-address)

Comment: Read my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8107860/362536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine multiple factors such as sessions, cookies and ip filters.

But of course users still be able to clear cookies and sessions.

You may try to get mac-id of user's pc or computer but it is complicated and dunno it is useful or not and also user still can change mac-id but it's not an easy thing to do.

Comment: You have piqued my interest... how do you propose to get the MAC?  You can't do it server-side for non-link-local connections, and AFAIK JavaScript is sandboxed to prevent access to that kind of information.  Did you have an interesting approach in mind?

Comment: `macshift -i "Local Area Network"` is hard for you?  Of course it is easy.  Also, you cannot even rely on the user **having** a MAC address.  You can fully use the internet without Ethernet, or other network types with MAC.  Ever heard of a dial-up modem?  Using the MAC is a very, very bad idea.